# Django Apache Application 404

Tags: python, django, apache

I have tried my Django Application using the Django application server and it works just fine.However when I try to use the application with Apache I get a 404 with every URL that I am routing. Below is the 404 error that I am getting:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.domain.com:8787/myapp
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^myapp/
^$
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, myapp, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

This is the first URLs file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^myapp/', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),

    # This was the orginal plan
    # (r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/myapp/list/'}), # Just for ease of use.

    (r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/myapp/index/'}), # Just for ease of use.

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is the second URLs Fil that (myproject.myapp.urls):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.myapp.views',
    url(r'^list/$', 'list', name='list'),
    url(r'^ass1/$', 'ass1', name='ass1'),
    url(r'^ass1v2/$', 'ass1v2', name='ass1v2'),
    url(r'^register/$','register', name='register'), # ADD NEW PATTERN!
    url(r'^login/$', 'user_login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'user_logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^index/$', 'index', name='index'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', 'category', name='category'),
    url(r'^indexAddJac444/$', 'indexAddJac444', name='indexAddJac444'),
)
```

This is the Apache Virtual Hosts file for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:8787>
    ServerAdmin test@localhost  

    WSGIDaemonProcess sampleapp python-path=/var/www/sampleapp:/var/www/sampleapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup sampleapp

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
        WSGIScriptAlias /myapp/index/ /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/static/
    Alias /myapp/ /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/myapp/

    <Directory /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/static>
    #Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/media>
    #Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/myapp>
    #Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    #Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I feel this close to solving the problem and know there is a solution. Do I need to further elaborate with more information? Please say. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check Apache logs (error log and access log).

Comment: Try to connect with `http://www.domain.com:8787/myapp/` with `/` at the end. If it works than you have problem with `/`.

Comment: These are the troubleshooting steps I have taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets think about it:

When you call `myapp/` it reads `url.py` and it see rule `myapp/` but it has to include `myproject.myapp.urls`. Probably at that moment it remove `myapp/` from url because it doesn't need it in file `myproject.myapp.urls` - so now you have empty string as url.

Now it searchs in `myproject.myapp.urls` but there is no rule for empty string.

I think you probably can connect with `/myapp/lists/` without problem - because there is the rule `^list/$` in `myproject.myapp.urls` - but you need rule `^$` in `myproject.myapp.urls` to connect with `/myapp/`

Comment: If my aswer helped you you can mark it as accepted (and upvote if you have enough reputation)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going to try your suggestion. So you are saying in myproject.myapp.urls I should have `(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/myapp/'}),`  ?

Comment: This way you redirect `/myapp/` to `/myapp/` so you get infinite loop. You need `url(r'^$', 'index', name='index')` and function `index` in `myproject.myapp.views`

Comment: I will be back at that computer to check this in a while.  Your suggestion is quite informative!

Comment: I see you already have `index` in `myproject.myapp.views` because you have `url(r'^index/$', 'index', name='index')` so you will have to use different name in `url(r'^$', 'index', name='index_2')`

Comment: Well I already have the index view, so its about routing it properly, Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Furas, first thing Monday

Comment: Hi Furas that solves part of the problem. However now when I try to access the view I now get a directory listing. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: Which view ? What url ? Normally Apache can list directory if it can't find index.html in folder.

Comment: I am simply trying _http://192.168.33.102:8787/myapp/_ and get a directory listing.  Also trying _http://192.168.33.102:8787/myapp/ass1v2/_ gives _NOT FOUND_

Comment: Well, try to: remove line with `Alias /myapp/` in `Apache Virtual Hosts file`.

Comment: Now using **WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sampleapp/JavaApp/for_django_1-4/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py**

Comment: I am still getting a directory listing for 192.168.33.102:8787/myapp and NOT FOUND for 192.168.33.102:8787/myapp/ass1v2